# HTTP POST request to JIRA using Java yields 400 bad request error, curl works fine

Tags: java, http, post, jira, jira-rest-api

So I'm trying to retrieve information about Jira issues through REST API using Java, however I keep getting the 400 error. I feel like there's something really stupid that I'm missing, can anyone help me find out what's wrong with this? EDIT: I realised that I'm not sending the username/password to Jira in the Java program, but I'm actually unsure how to do that... Help here would be great! Here is the code I have (company name edited):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JiraConnector 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            //store necessary query information
            URL jiraURL = new URL("http://jira.somecompany.com/rest/api/2/search");
            String data = "'{\"jql\":\"project = PROJ\"}'";

            //establish connection and request properties
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)jiraURL.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);

            connection.connect();

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0; System.out.print((char)c));

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.err.println("MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (java.net.UnknownServiceException e) {
            System.err.println("UnknownServiceException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }        
    }
}
```

For the record, using this curl command works:

```
curl -D- -u- user:password -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jql:"project=PROF"}' "http://jira.somecompany.com/rest/api/2/search"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heads up, the problem was authorization (in case anyone has this problem as well). Totally derped and forgot to send username/password.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have extra single quotes in the post data.

Instead of this:

```
String data = "'{\"jql\":\"project = PROJ\"}'";
```

try this:

```
String data = "{\"jql\":\"project = PROJ\"}";
```

Incidentally, even though you are getting a 400 Bad Request, JIRA is still providing useful information that helps localize the error. You can look at it using the connection's getErrorStream method. If we quickly slap this onto your code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JiraConnector 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            //store necessary query information
            URL jiraURL = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8082/rest/api/2/search");
            String data = "{\"jql\":\"project = PROJ\"}";

            //establish connection and request properties
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)jiraURL.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);

            connection.connect();

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0; System.out.print((char)c));

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.err.println("MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (java.net.UnknownServiceException e) {
            System.err.println("UnknownServiceException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage());

                    InputStream errorStream = connection.getErrorStream();
                    if (errorStream != null) {
                        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errorStream));
                        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0; System.out.print((char)c));
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e2) {
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

If you're going to be doing any serious work against the REST API, I would recommend looking at using [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net) instead of trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

A general tip first: use for instance FireFox with the TamperData add-on, which enables to trace a regular form submit, and inspect everything. In your case a proxy monitor might be more of a help. Also:

```
curl --trace-ascii ...
```

TamperData will show where it goes wrong.

Without encoding parameter the current platform encoding is taken; non-portable.

```
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        connection.getInputStream(),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a basic authorization header is easy enough:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)jiraURL.openConnection();
String userCredentials = "username:password";
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));
connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
```